# Как получить текст, заключенный в любые теги?

Tags: javascript

Ребят, как получить текст, заключенный в любые теги (в моем случае между тегами <i>)?

Comment: @rishat, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

Из одного или всех? Если из всех, то сохранять в виде массива?

Схематически так:

```
node.textContent
// или
node.innerHTML // поддерживается и в IE ниже 9, но получает HTML-контент, а не TEXT-контент
```

**UPD** Раз уж перевели комментарий в вопрос, то напишу более расширено. Для поиска элементов на странице, я бы рекомендовал использовать методы **querySelector** и **querySelectorAll**. [Хорошая поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) браузерами, использование селекторов. И [пара вариантов](http://jsfiddle.net/6694nrq5/) использования:

```
var d = document;
// Получаем текст из первого указанного элемента на странице
var firstSingle = d.querySelector('i');
console.log(firstSingle.textContent); // ABC
// Получаем текст из всех указанных элементов в виде массива
var allInArray = [].map.call(d.querySelectorAll('i'), function(el){
    return el.textContent;
});
console.log(allInArray); //  ["ABC", "DEF", "JHI"]
```

Comment: а разве innerText не катит?)

Comment: @knes, конечно же катит, но только для IE ))

----------

Не понимаю, почему мой комментарий в вопрос преобразовали. Хотел выслушать уточнения от ТС, а уже потом что-то конкретно описать...

Comment: > а разве innerText не катит?)

[Источник][1]
> Обратите внимание, что в коде
> используется *textContent* вместо
> *innerText*. Если использовать
> *innerText*, то код будет корректно
> работать только в браузерах Google
> Chrome [40.0.2214] и Opera [27.0], но
> не будет работать в IE [11] и Firefox
> [35.0.1]. В квадратных скобках указаны
> версии, для которых я проверял работу
> кода.


  [1]: http://webgl-bush.blogspot.ru/2015/02/blog-post.html

Comment: @moonlight, не знал, что в IE11 уже забили на innerText, но суть, собственно в одном - это свойство лучше не рассматривать, как какой-то вариант при разработке, что сам делаю и другим рекомендую ;)